# UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 805: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python-3.x

```py
#!/bin/python3
from collections import defaultdict
from surprise import Dataset, Reader, SVD
from surprise.model_selection import cross_validate
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Label, Entry, scrolledtext, DISABLED, END, NORMAL
import csv
import numpy
import os
import psutil
import random
import time


class MovieRatings:
    def __init__(self, master):
        # Set up the GUI
        self.master = master
        self.text = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(master, width=100, height=30)
        self.text.grid(row=6, column=0,)
        self.msg1 = Label(master, text="1. Train with the dataset")
        self.msg1.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.button = Button(master, text='Train Now', width=25, command=self.runner)
        self.button.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.msg3 = Label(master, text="2. Enter user IDs you would like to display predictions for (1-610).")
        self.msg3.grid(row=2, column=0)
        self.msg4 = Label(master, text="Separate values with commas. No spaces.")
        self.msg4.grid(row=3, column=0)
        self.userentry = Entry(master, width=40)
        self.userentry.grid(row=4, column=0)
        self.button2 = Button(master, text='Display Estimates', width=25, command=self.runner2)
        self.button2.grid(row=5, column=0)
        self.button2.configure(state=DISABLED)
        master.mainloop()

    # Used to print to the UI text box
    def printer(self, string):
        self.text.insert(END, string + "\n")
        self.master.update()

    # Enable a button
    def enableButton(self, button):
        button.configure(state=NORMAL)
        self.master.update()

    # Dsable a button
    def disableButton(self, button):
        button.configure(state=DISABLED)
        self.master.update()

    # Change the text on a button.
    def updateButton(self, string, button):
        button["text"] = string
        self.master.update()

    # Train on the dataset and predict ratings
    def runner(self):
        self.updateButton('Training now...', self.button)
        self.disableButton(self.button)
        results, trainset = self.trainer()
        self.updateButton('Training done!', self.button)
        self.predictions = self.predictor(results, trainset)
        self.enableButton(self.button2)

    # Display top 10 predictions for selected users
    def runner2(self):
        users = self.userentry.get().split(",")
        self.finder(self.predictions, users)

    # Get top 10 predictions
    def finder(self, predictions, users):
        top_movies = self.get_top_movies(users, predictions, 10)
        # Collect the movie IDs for the users' top movies
        movie_ids = []
        for user_id, ratings in top_movies.items():
            for movie_id, _ in ratings:
                movie_ids.append(movie_id)
        # Grab the titles and genres for the movie IDs
        movie_dict = self.get_movie_titles(movie_ids)
        # Print out the results
        counter = 1
        self.printer("\nPredicted top 10 movies for your selected users:\n")
        for user_id, ratings in top_movies.items():
            if counter == 11:
                counter = 1
            self.printer("User ID: " + user_id)
            for movie_id, prediction in ratings:
                current = movie_dict[movie_id]
                self.printer("\t#" + str(counter) + ". " + current[0])
                self.printer("\t\t" + current[1])
                self.printer("\t\tPredicted rating: {:0.3f}".format(prediction) + "\n")
                counter += 1

    # Predict ratings.
    def predictor(self, results, trainset):
        self.printer("\nNow predicting ratings for movies each user hasn't rated.")
        self.printer("Please wait...\n")
        # Test on an anti testset (effectively predicts how users will rate
        # movies they haven't watched yet).
        start = time.time()
        predictions = results.test(trainset.build_anti_testset())
        end = time.time()
        spent = end - start
        self.printer("Prediction time: {:0.3f} seconds".format(spent))
        process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
        self.printer("Memory used:")
        self.printer("{:0.5f}".format(process.memory_info().rss/1048576.0) + " MB Physical")
        self.printer("{:0.5f}".format(process.memory_info().vms/1048576.0) + " MB Virtual")
        return predictions

    # Train with the dataset
    def trainer(self):
        # Set the random seed that numpy (used internally by Surprise) will use.
        my_seed = random.randint(0, 2**32)
        random.seed(my_seed)
        numpy.random.seed(my_seed)
        # Reassurance that the script is actually running.
        self.printer("\nNow training on the MovieLens latest small dataset. (8 folds used)")
        self.printer("Please wait...\n")
        # Define the file's format
        reader = Reader(line_format='user item rating timestamp', sep=',')
        # Load the data from the ratings.csv file
        data = Dataset.load_from_file('./ml-latest-small/ratings.csv', reader=reader)
        # Use the SVD algorithm for prediction
        method = SVD()
        start = time.time()
        # Use 8-fold cross validation and evaluate the results with RMSE and MAE
        measurements = cross_validate(method, data, measures=['RMSE', 'MAE'],
                                      cv=8, verbose=False, n_jobs=-2, return_train_measures=True)
        # Print the random seed used for fold assignments
        self.printer("Random seed used for fold assignment: {}\n".format(my_seed))
        # Show the stats
        meanFitTime = numpy.mean(measurements["fit_time"])
        meanTestTime = numpy.mean(measurements["test_time"])
        meanTestMAE = numpy.mean(measurements["test_mae"])
        meanTestRMSE = numpy.mean(measurements["test_rmse"])
        meanTrainMAE = numpy.mean(measurements["train_mae"])
        meanTrainRMSE = numpy.mean(measurements["train_rmse"])
        self.printer("Mean fit time per fold: {:0.5f} seconds".format(meanFitTime))
        self.printer("Mean test time per fold: {:0.5f} seconds".format(meanTestTime))
        self.printer("Mean train MAE per fold: {:0.5f}".format(meanTrainMAE))
        self.printer("Mean train RMSE per fold: {:0.5f}".format(meanTrainRMSE))
        self.printer("Mean test MAE per fold: {:0.5f}".format(meanTestMAE))
        self.printer("Mean test RMSE per fold: {:0.5f}\n".format(meanTestRMSE))
        # Train with the dataset
        trainset = data.build_full_trainset()
        method.fit(trainset)
        end = time.time()
        spent = end - start
        self.printer("Training and testing time: {:0.3f} seconds\n".format(spent))
        process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
        self.printer("Memory used:")
        self.printer("{:0.5f}".format(process.memory_info().rss/1048576.0) + " MB Physical")
        self.printer("{:0.5f}".format(process.memory_info().vms/1048576.0) + " MB Virtual")
        return method, trainset

    # Get the top movies (top 5 by default) for a set of users
    def get_top_movies(self, users, predictions, k):
        # Set up an empy dictionary
        top_movies = defaultdict(list)
        # Read through the predicted ratings and store them in the dictionary
        for user, item, truth, prediction, _ in predictions:
            # Only store predictions for the requested users
            if user in users:
                top_movies[user].append((item, prediction))
        # Organize the ratings so that the top rated movies are first
        for user, ratings in top_movies.items():
            ratings.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
            top_movies[user] = ratings[:k]
        return top_movies

    # Convert movie IDs to titles and also get genres
    def get_movie_titles(self, movie_ids):
        # Set up an empty dictionary
        movie_dict = defaultdict(list)
        # Open the movies CSV file.
        with open('./ml-latest-small/movies.csv', "r") as csvfile:
            reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
            # Read each row
            for row in reader:
                # Store the movie title if the ID matches
                if row[0] in movie_ids:
                    movie_dict[row[0]] = [row[1], row[2]]
        return movie_dict


master = Tk()
MovieRatings(master)
master.mainloop()
```

Comment: You should find the piece of code where you get this error (shown in the traceback), run that on its own as an [mcve] and ask *that* as a question. What you have now is a bunch of code, 99% irrelevant to your problem, without actually even asking a question.

Comment: I'm still a beginner in python

Comment: you need to show some attempt at debugging and isolating your code, the stack trace of the error should tell you which line number the problem occurs on. You can then write a small isolated code to reproduce the issue

Comment: @ChrisDoyle thank you. But I'm still a beginner as I said. I only know the basics of python. I need this for a university Project

Comment: Can someone help me by skype ?

Comment: so you cant just paste the error you got cause your a beginner? it will give you the line number of where the error number occured. We cant run your full code and we dont want to debug by hand all the lines you pasted so you do need to show some effort if you want people to help you.

Comment: Alright, I think I found the problem.